# Drupal 7 field for expandable list

Tags: 7, entities

I'm looking for a module that provides a D7 field type that's an expandable list: a list where new values can be added at run-time. Is there a module for that?

Comment: Do you want the new values added to be available to other user's also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a taxonomy term reference with a tag widget.